# Loop through a String Array

Tags: vba, string, loops, for-loop

I would like to implement a loop through a String-array.
The Strings vParam are identifiers of the tabs I want to scroll through. I want to open each of them and add the String "Serial number" in the Cell A1.
Following you find my piece of code. Unfortunately it is not working yet. The debugger says that the object is not supporting the method. Could anyone please tell me what's wrong with my code?

```
Dim outManual As String
Dim outSystem As String
Dim vParam As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim diff As Integer
vParam = Array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")

For x = LBound(vParam) To UBound(vParam)
    Workbooks(Stamm).Worksheets(vParam).Cells(1, 1).Value = "Serial number"
       
Next
```

Thank you!

Comment: `Workbooks(Stamm).Worksheets(vParam(x))....`

Comment: Thank you! The String appears in the cells if I execute the Makro several times. Could it also work at once without having me to execute it that often?  Am I right, that this piece of code (x = LBound(vParam) To UBound(vParam)) is starting the loop itself?

Comment: Yes `For x = ...` is the loop. I'm not sure I understand your first question.

Comment: Yeah it is pretty confusing. I execute the Makro and nothing happens, when I execute it one more time, some tabs are changed. As if there is no loop implemented